# Random Background Color using LESS to multiple class-element

Tags: html, css, less

I saw different codes here for LESS, though more of it are not working in my end. I have maximum 5 colors to use to each panel as background, but these panels are depends on how many entries via database. Then, I have to create LESS function of (something like) foreach that assign these colors to different panels.

```
<div class="column">
 <figure class="panel"> <!-- content goes here --> </figure>
</div>

<div class="column">
 <figure class="panel"> <!-- content goes here --> </figure>
</div>

<div class="column">
 <figure class="panel"> <!-- content goes here --> </figure>
</div>

<div class="column">
 <figure class="panel"> <!-- content goes here --> </figure>
</div>
```

While my LESS code is:

```
.column {
  &:nth-child(1) > .panel { background: @red;; }
  &:nth-child(2) > .panel { background: @yellow; }
  &:nth-child(3) > .panel { background: @blue; }
  &:nth-child(4) > .panel { background: #99bf38; }
  &:nth-child(5) > .panel { background: #6d564b; }
}
```

So instead of creating bunches of `:nth-child()` to my LESS, is there a proper way of simplifying this to CSS LESS only? If there's new entry I have to create another `:nth-child()` and repeat the background color.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think u'd better achieve this with js, since u don't know how many entries there.

Comment: @blackmiaool yeah it seems like that will be my last resort.

Comment: Would you loop through a set of background-colors?